# Allow multiple inputs from one inputbox in QGIS Processing Script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I am trying to build a processing script using "Create new script from template". I want the user to have the opportunity to insert multiple values into one field.

```
def initAlgorithm():        
   self.addParameter(
        QgsProcessingParameterNumber(
            self.INPUT3,
            self.tr('Insert Numbers')
         )
...
...
def processAlgorithm():
   source3=self.parameterAsInt(
       parameters,
       self.INPUT3,
       context)
```

I know that `QgsProcessingParameterNumber` allows inserting only one value and there is no `allowMultiple` option.
Which command should I use to get data like [1,2,3,8,7] from one inputbox?

QGIS v3.20.

Comment: I added the parameters as QgsProcessingParameterString separated by commas then transformed it to integers.

Answer (score 3):

Use `QgsProcessingParameterString` and split the string by comma as below:

```
def initAlgorithm():        
    self.addParameter(
        QgsProcessingParameterString(self.INPUT3,self.tr('Insert Numbers'))

...

def processAlgorithm():
    source3 = self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.INPUT3, context)

    numbers = source3.split(",")
```

Comment: I already did that. I wanted to know if there was another way but thank you!

Comment: I am aware of that. It's better to add as a proper answer. People don't tend to read comments.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answer already given above, there are two issues I wanted to point out with it you might want to be aware of.

1. The above example code fails when a separator other than "," is used. You could implement a split by multiple separators (multiple ways to do this can be found in other threads), or just add a hint saying as much to the self.tr string.
2. The list resulting from the split string method will still contain strings. I solved this by adding the following list comprehension:

```py
source.replace(" ","") # to be safe, remove all whitespaces from the input string
# split by separating comma, and immediately convert to int
numbers = [int(x) for x in source.split(",")]
```

So in full:

```py
def initAlgorithm(self):        
    self.addParameter(
        QgsProcessingParameterString(
            self.INPUT,
            self.tr('Insert Numbers (separated by commas ",")')))

...


def processAlgorithm(self):
    source = self.parameterAsString(
        parameters, self.INPUT, context) # get input as STRING
    source.replace(" ","")
    numbers = [int(x) for x in source.split(",")]
```